Copy-PnPFile to copy Folder contents only not the top-level folder i
I'm using the cooy-pnpfile command to copy content from a specific folder in a doc lib to another doc lib
I don't want it to create a top folder in destination but just copy the folders and files.
Is it possible with this command. Currently when I look at my destination doc library what I see is a top folder from the source.
Thanks
